# c variables and equation

Tags: c, variables, equation

Updated code and question thanks to Sankalp Bhamare : The updated code is not getting the expected value in variable `twoHundredFiftyScholarship`.

When using the debugger I can see that the only value that is incorrect is for variable `twoHundredFiftyScholarship`.

The expected value for variable `twoHundredFiftyScholarship` when entering the sample run #1 should be 1. The value I get is 3.

same thing with for sample run #2. The expected value is 8. The value I get is 48.

---

Sample Run #1

How much was in the fund last year?

40000

What is the yearly percentage rate?

2

0 $1000 scholarships will be awarded.

1 $500 scholarships will be awarded.

1 $250 scholarships will be awarded.

Sample Run #2

How much was in the fund last year?

1200000

What is the yearly percentage rate?

1

5 $1000 scholarships will be awarded.

10 $500 scholarships will be awarded.

8 $250 scholarships will be awarded.

The expected value for variable `twoHundredFiftyScholarship` when entering the sample run #2 should be 8. The value I get is 48.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

    double fundAmount;
    int yearlyInterestRate;
    double yearlyInterest;
    double remainingScholarship;
    int thousandScholarships = 0;
    int fiveHundredScholarship = 0;
    int twoHundredFiftyScholarship = 0;


    printf("How much was in the fund last year?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &fundAmount);

    printf("What is the yearly percentage rate?\n");
    scanf("%d", &yearlyInterestRate);

    yearlyInterest = fundAmount*yearlyInterestRate/100.0;
    remainingScholarship = yearlyInterest;
    thousandScholarships = remainingScholarship/1000.0;
    fiveHundredScholarship = remainingScholarship/500.0;
    twoHundredFiftyScholarship = remainingScholarship/250.0;

    if(thousandScholarships > 5){
        thousandScholarships = 5;

        remainingScholarship -= thousandScholarships*1000.0;}


    if(fiveHundredScholarship > 10){
        fiveHundredScholarship = 10;

        remainingScholarship -= fiveHundredScholarship*500;}



        remainingScholarship -= twoHundredFiftyScholarship*250;



        printf("%d $1000 scholarships will be awarded.\n",thousandScholarships);
        printf("%d $500 scholarships will be awarded.\n",fiveHundredScholarship);       
        printf("%d $250 scholarships will be awarded.\n",twoHundredFiftyScholarship);



    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, what makes you think your equation is wrong? What value are you getting, and what value do you expect?

Comment: Also, where does your `scholarship` variable come from?

Comment: Regarding how many variables you need, that question is essentially "how do I write my code?", as once you have the code written, you will know how many variables you need. It is not something you need to know before writing the code.

Comment: significance of "yearly_PERCENT_rate"? It is not used int thee question you described?
If possible give an example using yearly_PERCENT_rate, then it will be more clear how it can be used in your equation?

Comment: @cipher94 I have match the variables now. Thanks / percent_RATE

Comment: @lxop I meant to type `scholarship1000`.

Comment: What is Amount_in_found? I thought it was a typo for Amount_in_fund, but Amount_in_found occurs in your code too.

Comment: @gmatht it was! thx for that

Comment: Notice that StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* site

Comment: I'll just leave this here: modulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the above simply as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    double fundAmount = 100350.0;
    double yearlyInterestRate = 9.0;
    double yearlyInterest = fundAmount*yearlyInterestRate/100.0;

    double remainingScholarship = yearlyInterest;

    int thousandScholarships = remainingScholarship/1000.0;
    if(thousandScholarships > 5)
        thousandScholarships = 5;

    remainingScholarship -= thousandScholarships*1000.0;

    int fiveHundredScholarship = remainingScholarship/500.0;
    if (fiveHundredScholarship > 10)
        fiveHundredScholarship = 10;

    remainingScholarship -= fiveHundredScholarship*500;
    int twoHundredFiftyScholarship = remainingScholarship/250.0;
    remainingScholarship -= twoHundredFiftyScholarship*250;

    printf("$1000 Scholarships : %d\n",thousandScholarships);
    printf("$500 Scholarships : %d\n",fiveHundredScholarship);
    printf("$250 Scholarships : %d\n",twoHundredFiftyScholarship);
    printf("Residual Amount : %lf\n",remainingScholarship);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for your help. I have updated the code with your help, and now I'm having an issue I added to the original post. thanks again.

Comment: Kakarotto you have wrongly updated the code. In your `if(thousandScholarships > 5) {` there should be no bracket following `if` , if you refer to my answer, I have only the `if` clause and have no `brackets` after it! PS. Repeat same for `fiveHundredScholarships`  this will fix your error, also note that you should carefully refer to my code! I suggest you that you first run my code as it is...

Comment: thank you. I did run the code as it is. I'm only trying to implement user input for `fundAmount` and `yearlyInterestRate`. I have removed the braket after `if` but I get the same problem.

Comment: I got it! I miss placed one of the equations. Checking with your code I was able to realize that.  :)

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: How many variables are needed for this problem?

That question makes no sense. Imagine you have one variable declared as `int x;` then you could code

```
int x1 = x;
int x2 = x*1;
int x3 = x+0;
int x4 = x|0;
```

then all of `x`, `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` contain the same integer value and could be used interchangeably.

Imagine also that you have two variables and code

```
int x= something();
int y= x+1;
```

then (if `y` is not changed later) you could substitute occurrences of `y` with `x+1`.

Be sure to read more about the C programming language (notably [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).